# autocomplete in android not working with dynamic data

Tags: android

I am facing problem with auto complete in android. Instead of hard coding data in Activity itself, I tried to read the data dynamically from other application on every key press which is matched. Please find below my program and suggest me where I am wrong.

Note: at the first time key press, the results are getting populated. After that if I clear the entered text and enter different character, the results are not getting shown in the auto complete drop down box. I am getting from other application on every key press but not getting populated in auto complete drop down box.

I tried with textView.showDropDown(); and adapter.setNotifyOnChange(true); options. But no use.

```
package com.util;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.StatusLine;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;

public class HelloAutoCompleteActivity extends Activity {
List countries = new ArrayList();
    String url = ""; //some application url
AutoCompleteTextView textView;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    textView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autocomplete_country);
    textView.addTextChangedListener(new CostomTextWatcher());
    textView.setThreshold(1);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, countries);
    textView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

private class CostomTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
            int count) {
        if (s.length() > 0) {
            countries.clear();
            String readTwitterFeed = readFeed(s.toString());
            System.out.println(readTwitterFeed);
            try {
                JSONObject menuObject = new JSONObject(readTwitterFeed);
                JSONArray menuitemArray = menuObject
                        .getJSONArray("objectNameList");
                for (int i = 0; i < menuitemArray.length(); i++) {
                    System.out.println(menuitemArray.get(i));
                    countries.add(menuitemArray.get(i).toString());
                }
                // adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                // adapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);
                // textView.setAdapter(adapter);
                // textView.setThreshold(1);
                // textView.setAdapter(adapter);
                // textView.showDropDown();
                // adapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

public String readFeed(String val) {

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(
            url);
    try {
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
        StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
        int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
        if (statusCode == 200) {
            System.out.println("200");
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream content = entity.getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(content));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                builder.append(line);
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("else block");
            Log.e(HelloAutoCompleteActivity.class.toString(),
                    "Failed to download file");
        }
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```

}

Comment: I think you should read again concept of AutocompleteEditText. Filtration process automatically handled, why you are trying to filter? Can you explain it more?

Comment: Can you help me on this . How to proceed further?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the Filter interface to implement this as well. Turns out Filter.performFiltering() is called off the UI thread just for this type of purpose. Here is some code I use to do this:

```
 Filter filter = new Filter() {

    @Override
    public CharSequence convertResultToString(Object resultValue) {
        return resultValue.toString();
    }

    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {
        if( charSequence == null ) return null;
        try {
            // This call hits the server with the name I'm looking for and parses the JSON returned for the first 25 results
            PagedResult results = searchByName( charSequence.toString(), 1, 25, true);
            FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
            filterResults.values = results.getResults();
            filterResults.count = results.getResults().size();
            return filterResults;
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            return new FilterResults();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
        if( filterResults != null ) {
            adapter.clear();
            adapter.addAll( (List<MyObject>)filterResults.values );
        }
    }
};
```

Then using the Filter:

```
    private AutoCompleteTextView beverageName;
    ...

    beverageName = findViewById( R.id.beverageName );
    ListAdapter adapter = ...
    adapter.setFilter(filter);
    beverageName.setAdapter(adapter);
```

or u can use this link also

```
http://www.grobmeier.de/android-autocomplete-with-json-data-served-by-struts-2-05122011.html
```

Comment: I tried with the above hint. But did not work. Any help on this?

Comment: I have resolved my issue by adding this line : i.e.  adapter.addAll(countries); after fetching the results.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know what JSON you are using to parse. But here is an example of dynamic auto complete using Wikipedia Suggest JSON. All you need to do is change the JSON Part.

```
package com.yourapplication.wiki;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;

public class WikiSuggestActivity extends Activity {
    public String data;
    public List<String> suggest;
    public AutoCompleteTextView autoComplete;
    public ArrayAdapter<String> aAdapter;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        suggest = new ArrayList<String>();
        autoComplete = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1);
        autoComplete.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                String newText = s.toString();
                new getJson().execute(newText);
            }

        });

    }
   class getJson extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... key) {
        String newText = key[0];
        newText = newText.trim();
        newText = newText.replace(" ", "+");
        try{
            HttpClient hClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet hGet = new HttpGet("http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search="+newText+"&limit=8&namespace=0&format=json");
            ResponseHandler<String> rHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            data = hClient.execute(hGet,rHandler);
            suggest = new ArrayList<String>();
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(data);
            for(int i=0;i<jArray.getJSONArray(1).length();i++){
            String SuggestKey = jArray.getJSONArray(1).getString(i);
            suggest.add(SuggestKey);
            }

        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.w("Error", e.getMessage());
        }
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                 aAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.item,suggest);
                 autoComplete.setAdapter(aAdapter);
                 aAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

        return null;
    }

   }
}
```

Hope it helps Thank You!.